# I am hosting a Discord Bot on Heroku it just gives me out error 14 ps webscale doesnt work either

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, web-hosting

I am hosting a Discord.py Bot on Heroku.

I am getting error code H 14

My `procfile` is below:

```
worker: python "Main Script.py"
```

My requirements file contains:

```
discord
```

I tried running the following command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

but it just says couldn't find the web process type.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

- Your `Procfile` must be called `Procfile` *exactly*. You spell it all lowercase in your quesiton, but it needs a capital `P`.
- Your `Procfile` only defines a worker process. I'm not sure why you are trying to scale up a web process. Try

  ```
  heroku ps:scale worker=1
  ```

  instead.
- Or, if your `Main Script.py` is supposed to listen for HTTP requests, define it as a `web` process in your `Procfile:

  ```
  web: python "Main Script.py"
  ```

  In this case, make sure you're binding to the port Heroku assigns you via the `PORT` environment variable.

I suggest renaming your file as well, e.g. to `main.py`, but that shouldn't cause anything to break.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me out <br>

even after 
```heroku ps:scale worker=1```
in my Procfile, it is still giving H14 error

also i changed the name to main.py and i am still getting error